# Qty increments, and Upsert issues

Tags: vb.net, upsert

Having quite a bit of trouble with code.  I'm attempting to do a basic upsert, and can get the insert command to work without issues, however the Select and update aren't playing nice together.  I've tried a variety of ways to configure parameters, and all the examples/building it from the ground up has failed quite horribly if I do say so myself.

Please note I picked up VB.Net and programing in general roughly 2 weeks ago.

So what I'm looking for is a real world sample of configuring parameters, and/or what could be wrong with the select and update statements.  I'm fairly certain that the issue isn't with the select statement itself more along the lines of <>  Every time it's been debugged it returns with count of 0 even though there is data present on the table.

Currently using VB Studio Express 2010, VB.Net, and an Access DB

```
    Dim sel As String = "SELECT ID FROM Stock WHERE ID = '" & txtID.Text & "'"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sel, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If dt.Rows.Count < 1 Then
            If radAdd.Checked = True Then
                Dim dbUP As String = ("Update Stock SET Qty = Qty +1 Where ID = '" & txtID.Text & "'")
                Dim cmdup As New OleDbCommand(dbUP, conn)
                cmdup.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Else
                Dim dbDW As String = ("Update Stock SET Qty = Qty -1 Where ID = '" & txtID.Text & "'")
                Dim cmdw As New OleDbCommand(dbDW, conn)
                cmdw.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Else
            Dim dbIns As String = "INSERT INTO Stock (ID, Qty, LastDate)"" VALUES ('" & txtID.Text & "', 1, Now())"
            Dim dc As New OleDbCommand(dbIns, conn)
            dc.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
```

Comment: Be advised that your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Well aware, that's why I'm looking for a real world example to configuring parameters.  Just not a lot of examples out there for oldb.  I don't have access to the SQL server yet, thus having to use access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is change the following two lines:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
If dt.Rows.Count < 1 Then
```

to:
    Dim oValue As Object

```
oValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
If oValue IsNot Nothing AndAlso oValue IsNot DBNull.Value Then
```

What this does is just retrieves the single value from the select command and, if it is not null, then something exists, so you fall into the update code. If the record does not exist, the code will return dbnull.value or nothing and you will proceed to your insert code.

Comment: When I replaced and inserted this line the value returned is {} repeating.  i.e. when I go into debug the result is tree after tree of Value {}. So it always believes the condition isn't null so it has to update.  Tried it with both Select ID and Select *

Comment: @HBlakei: couple of questions: 1) I'm assuming that you also removed the dt.Rows.Count check? 2) When you step through this code in debug, is txtID.Text changing or is it always the same?

Comment: I did remove both lines.  I did however figure out how to configure this line to where it works.

If cmd.ExecuteScalar() IsNot Nothing Then

Will this code cause any issues?

Comment: @HBlakei: Ah, it seems that access treats the return value differently than SQL Server (which is what I am used to). Your solution will not cause any problems. I will update the answer to reflect this and support either invalid value.